# Execlp why doesn't this work?

Tags: c, exec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    execlp("echo", "echo", "hello", (char *)NULL);
    execlp("echo", "echo", "hey", (char *)NULL);
    execlp("echo", "echo", "bye", (char *)NULL);
    execlp("echo", "echo", "sup", (char *)NULL);
    execlp("echo", "echo", "hi", (char *)NULL);
}
```

> ```
> error: test2.c: In function ‘main’:
>   test2.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execlp’ [-
>   Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>   execlp("echo", "echo", "hello", (char *)NULL);
>   ^
>   test2.c:
> ```

Oh, nvm I had to include unistd, but even after that it only prints out "hello"?

```
$ gcc -Wall above.c
$ ./a.out
hello
```

Comment: try including unistd.h `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: Look up what execlp does.